# Changing the Navigation Drawer menu on click

Tags: android, listview, navigation, drawer

I have created a Basic Navigation Menu Drawer. What I want to do is change the Navigation Menu layout when i click on an Option.
For example: My menu has Men, Women, Child. When I click on Men, I want to load another list in the same Navigation Drawer with menu containing Jeans, Shirts etc.

I have already created both the Lists, in a ListView, but I am unable to inflate the list in the Navigation drawer on Click of the first Menu.
I have already checked Google and Stackoverflow but there seems to be no answer.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use Expendable List View for making submenu in drawer.

Comment: @VishalChauhan I know but that is not what i am looking for. I want the change the Navigation Menu completely by changing it with the new Menu.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in comment that you want to change the navigation menu completely then do not make a ListView or navigation view directly in Drawer layout.

Make navigation menu as a fragment in Drawer layout and in fragment layout xml you can create a list view. Then you can easily replace one fragment(that contain menu and sub menu list) to another.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:background="#ffffff">

//main content view
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
   the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="Your's Base menu list fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/drawer_drawer" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.